# Get the Element Value in the XML by using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the values of the XML file by using LINQ to XML.

Here is sample block of the XML file.

```
<SECTION NAME="Details">
    <COLUMNS>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.STOCK_CODE">CODE A</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.DESCRIPTION">Product A</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.SALES_PRICE">43.65</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.SUPPLIER_PART_NUMBER"></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.UNIT_WEIGHT">65.50</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.OUT_OF_STOCK">0</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.BRAND">ADDIDAS</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.CATEGORY1">MEN</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.CATEGORY2">TOILETERIES</COLUMN>
    </COLUMNS>
</SECTION>
<SECTION NAME="Details">
    <COLUMNS>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.STOCK_CODE">CODE B</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.DESCRIPTION">Product B</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.SALES_PRICE">18.95</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.SUPPLIER_PART_NUMBER">30.45</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.UNIT_WEIGHT">38.50</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.OUT_OF_STOCK">0</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.BRAND">REVLON</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.CATEGORY1">WOMEN</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="STOCK.CATEGORY2">PERFUMES</COLUMN>
    </COLUMNS>
</SECTION>
```

I used LINQ to XML to get the values into the Object.  Instead of using the Fixed Position, I would like to get the values by using the Value of the "NAME".  Please guide me how I could select the values?  Thanks.

```
foreach (var page in root.Elements("PAGE").Elements("SECTIONS").Elements("SECTION"))
                {
                    CurrentProduct = string.Empty;

                    if (page.Attribute("NAME").Value == "Details")
                    {
                        var sec = page.Element("COLUMNS");

                        UploadPrice pp = new UploadPrice();

                        pp.Code = sec.Elements("COLUMN").ElementAt(0).Value;
                        pp.Net = sec.Elements("COLUMN").ElementAt(2).Value;
                        pp.POR25 = sec.Elements("COLUMN").ElementAt(3).Value;
                        pp.SSP = sec.Elements("COLUMN").ElementAt(4).Value;

                        UploadPrices.Add(pp);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use e.g. `pp.Code = sec.Elements("COLUMN").First(c => c.Attribute("NAME").Value == "STOCK.STOCK_CODE").Value;` and so on.